# Strcmp outputs a negative value when comparing files

Tags: php

What I need to know is why my `strcmp` outputs -11?

I have checked both files, the result is the same as

> Magnum 23-08-2011 1st 0006,2nd 0661,3rd
>   6358,S:2359,5341,3075,4048,3720,8648,2774,7109,6360,1422,C:6149,0303,4841,3606,0076,2648,6736,7978,5986,7051

Here is my code:

```
$checkfile2 = fopen("/var/www/html/magnum/check.txt","r");
fclose($checkfile2);

$checkfile3 = fopen("/var/www/html/magnum/result/".$Current."Magnumresult.txt","r");
fclose($checkfile3);

echo strcmp($checkfile2, $checkfile3);
```

Thank you, hope you guys reply to me soon.

Comment: And what is the question? Difference between actual and expected behavior? What do you want to do anyway?

Comment: I suggest you read the [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) manual page, paying particular attention to the return value

Comment: You want to compare the *contents* of each file, not their associated "file pointer resources" returned from `fopen()`. If only there were some way to get the contents of a file.

Comment: `fopen()` does what it says it does :)

Answer (score 2):

[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function return a file pointer resource not string. So you are getting the error.

If you want to compare contents of each file then use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to get the contents of each file.